# How can I make an iDevice app with a 1 week trial period, and after that, requires the user to pay?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

i am developing an iDevice chat application. The user of this application can use it free for 1 week, but after the trial period is over, the user needs to make an in-app purchase for $1.99 to continue using the app, or it will be disabled. Does Apple accept such a condition, and if so how do I implement it? Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I've been to your link, and I think there is no relevant content on that page. Please consider editing your link.

Answer (score 8):

Apple will not accept it. App Store Review Guidelines state that:

1. Apps containing "rental" content or services that expire after a limited time are not permitted
2. Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions are not permitted

Based on your description, the app will be a trial one after expiration, so it will become unusable, which is not allowed.

In order to avoid the app to be rejected for the reasons above, you should provide for the app at least a minimum functionality after the trial period expires. E.g. you can offer unlimited chat messages by IAP and, for people that don't unlock this feature, you can offer a maximum of 10 or so messages per day, or intermix messages with ads.